# How to install android support repository offline

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to compile this library :

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
```

but this error showing up:

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1 install repository and sync project
```

so I tried to update my android support repository but my Internet speed is bad so I download the support repository using IDM (Internet Download Manager), but now I don't know how to install it ,I tried this way :

1.Extract the downloaded zip file.

2.Copy the folder named m2repository from the extracted folder.

3.Navigate to extras/android directory in your SDK installation directory. For me it's:C:\Users\$usrname$\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\

5.Replace the existing m2repository folder with the one from the ZIP.

**But this error still exists Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1 install repository and sync project**

Comment: I'm confused... So you downloaded a library anyway? Why didn't you just let the Android SDK finish the download? IDM isn't any better and now you are at risk for deleting the entire m2repository folder and deleting all the other libraries

Answer (score -1):

In your project's `build.gradle` your should have this section :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // support for Google's Maven repo using the google() method. Includes tools + support libs.
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

See also this help : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup#add-library

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Furthermore, the library you're using is listed here : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven at **Google's Maven repository**

Comment: And for offline repo : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#offline-google-maven

Comment: That requires you to be **online** to install (or download) the library...